# jBPM deployment as Web application

Tags: jboss, jbpm, business-process-management

I'm a newbie to jBPM kind.

I managed to create a workflow using Eclispse plug-in.

I'm executing the workflow as a "JAVA application"

It works fine.

Now, i want my workflow to be executed from multiple & different client.

So i'm looking for guides to execute like a web application.

Is it possible ?

How to execute the jBPM process like a web application?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time, i'm able create a jBPM web application.

Following the link, https://community.jboss.org/people/roxy1987/blog/2013/01/22/jbpm5-web-application-example

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you are already using jBPM as a library of your java project. If you want to use it in a webapp there's nothing special you must do. Create a new webapp project, add jBPM5 dependencies/libraries and start creating your kbases, ksessions and so on.

Best Regards,

Comment: i tried this, quite unsure about the dependencies for jBPM5. Any example proj ?